# starting mongod via ansible

Tags: mongodb, ansible

as mentionned in the title, I have an ansible role that installs MongoDB perfectly.
Now I want to start mongod after installation is done
I tried :

```
- name: Start mongod
  command: mongod
```

but when I run the role, the output freezes in that task

So any ideas on how to start mongod via ansible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this, that the mongodb start to run and the ansible waiting for the stop. But it won't be stop, because it is running. Create a systemd configuration for the mongodb and start it with the service ansible module.

Comment: indeed, that was the problem, as u said I ended up using upstart

Comment: IS there a tutorial somewhere that explains this in more detail?

Comment: Look around systemctl or systemd files. These widely used by the systems like CentOS, Fedora, Ubunut maybe.

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to go with the init/startup script as @PumpkinSeed said but if you want to continue like this, then you can do like this:

```
- name: Start mongod
  shell: "mongod &"
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: This is not the right way. Processes must be delegated to a proc manager. If you still need to do this, `mongod& > /dev/null` is the right shell command. This Ansible task will never end.

Comment: I already used "mongod &" but I didn't get what i wanted, so I think the best solution as mentionned is to use upstart or systemd